# Jython generate class files

Tags: java, python, class, jython

I would like to know if it is possible to **generate class files corresponding to my Jython program**.

I found this :

```
$> jython -m compileall myfolder
```

This does generate class files with coherent names compared to my jython files (.py), but I have absolutely no idea how to use them and even if it is what I am looking for...

If ever it is possible, a very basic exemple would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: See [Jython Compiler](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/jythonc.html)